# VBA- Iterate over an Array of Cells to get an Password depends on a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I want to iterate over a list filled with name (Merkmal) and Passwords.

If I get the right name, the related password should be used to encode a new Excel  file.

I got two kinds of errors:

1. next without For
2. If without ending if

```
Sub Copy2newfile()
    zeile = 3
    Dim aKopf As Range
    Set aKopf = Range("A1:Y3")
    Dim Password As String

    Do
        ' Bereich kopieren
        altezeile = zeile + 1
        zeile = zeile + 1
        Merkmal = Range("F" & zeile).Value
        Do While Range("F" & zeile).Value = Merkmal
            zeile = zeile + 1
        Loop
        zeile = zeile - 1
        Range("A" & altezeile & ":Y" & zeile).Copy

        Password = generatePassword(Merkmal)


        ' In neue Datei einfügen
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        aKopf.Copy
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial


        'Speichern und schließen
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\1000len-4723\Desktop\Test_" & Merkmal & ".xlsx"
        ActiveWindow.Close
    Loop While Range("F" & zeile + 1).Value <> ""

End Sub

Function generatePassword(Merkmal)
    Dim zeile As Integer
    Dim Password As String
    Dim pswarray As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
    zeile = 2
    Set pswarray = Range("B")

    For Each cell In pswarray
        If cell = Merkmal Then
            Password = ("C" & zeile)
            zeile = zeile + 1
    Next cell

End Function
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Look at your function - you are missing an `end if`.

Comment: Quite some stuff to improve on in your code. One thing you might be interested in is `Range.Find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing and end if here:

```
    For Each cell In pswarray
        If cell = Merkmal Then
            Password = ("C" & zeile)
            zeile = zeile + 1
        End If '<<---- this was missing.
    Next cell
```